# (iMacros) How to scrape usernames this way?

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

So I manage to make it work, but it also scrapes the name
inside the box like this

[image]

And all I want it to scrape is the username "nekoakatsuki"
the code I use to scrape the username box is this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:infolist&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

**so it scrapes anything in the "infolist" and look below is
what it grabs which is also the name**

```
<div class="infolist">
<strong><a href="/n/nekoakatsuki/">nekoakatsuki</a></strong>
<br>
<span class="fullname">Jennifer Sandoval</span>
</div>
```

So how would I only scrape the username and not the Name also?

Website I'm using for this is http://web.stagram.com/tag/anime/?vm=grid

Answer (score 1):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:fullname EXTRACT=TXT
```

Try this.